# Static variable destructor

Tags: c++, variables, static, destructor

i am wondering why if i have code like this:

```
class Test2 {
 public:
 Test2() { std::cout << "TEST2 Constructor\n"; } 
 ~Test2() { std::cout << "TEST2 Destructor\n"; }  
};

class Test {
 public:
 static Test2& get() { static Test2 test{}; return test; }
};

int main()
{
    auto test = Test::get();
    std::cout << "Created\n";
    
    auto test1 = Test::get();
    std::cout << "Created\n";
    
    auto test2 = Test::get();
    std::cout << "Created\n";    
}
```

i've got output like this:

```
> TEST2 Constructor 
> Created 
> Created 
> Created 
> TEST2 Destructor 
> TEST2 Destructor 
> TEST2 Destructor 
> TEST2 Destructor
```

Why destructor is beeing called four times? Isn't there should be only one instance of Test?

Comment: `auto` is never a reference type.

Comment: When instrumenting constructor/destructor, don't forget copy/move.

Comment: Why not? You created four instances, three of them via copy steps, so four instances got destroyed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Destructor is being called 4 times as there are 4 objects that got created. This statement

`auto test1 = Test::get();`

calls the copy-constructor of `Test` class. You can verify by having a copy constructor with `cout` statement. `auto` resolves to `Test` not `Test&`. If you want to get the reference of the object, it has to be said explicitly

`auto& test1 = Test::get();`

Always follow [Rule of 3/5/0](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) if you are definining your own implementations for destructor/copy/move constructor.

Answer (score 0):

`test`, `test1` and `test2` are all instances of `Test`, and they get destructed at the end of `main` as expected. You do not see them get constructed because you didn't instrument the move-constructor with which they are initialized.